# Return concrete object to generic method with generic Map parameter during override

Tags: java, oop, generics

I  have a generic method with generic Map parameter. I want to override it and use concrete subtype, but without cast I am not able to return my subtype

```
public interface GarrageSimple {
    <T extends Car> T getCar(Map<String, T> c);
}
```

Implementation is below which gives error as: *Incompatible types. Required: **T** Found: **Bmw***

```
public class GarrageSimpleImpl implements GarrageSimple {

    @Override
    public <T extends Car> T getCar(Map<String, T> c) {
        return new Bmw();
    }
}
```

Actually, Bmw is a subclass of Car which means a type of T. When I cast it like * return (T)new Bmw();* it works with a warning that **Unchecked cast Bmw to T**

I know that it is because I take a risk to return concrete subclass while method signature is generic, but how I can change my method to make it concrete and not break override signature?
If I can, in that case, it should work as expected.

PS: I don't want to make my class generic, I just need to change my method signature to make it concrete during implementation.

Thanks

Comment: Why you use generics?  
Not just:  
  
    Car getCar(Map<String, Car> c);  
      
    @Override  
    public Car getCar(Map<String, Car> c) {  
      return new Bmw();  
    }

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I can but, I want to avoid cast each time. Also, this code is a simulation of a real system. We have some part of the system already implemented. 
And I just want to understand is it possible to override it to use concrete subclass or not.

Comment: What if someone called `getCar(new HashMap<String,VW>())`?

Comment: thanks. yes, this is root cause of given error. But question is how make changes on override method to use subclas (Bmw) in method signature but dont break override logic?

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do. Either you want to return an element of the `Map`, then your method signature is good. Or you want to put a new value into the map, then it should be `? super Car`. Or you want to do something else; in this case, what's the relationship between the map's value's type and the returned type supposed to be/mean?

Comment: I didn't put any logic related to given map param. But u can consider it that I get value from it and do something with it. But it is not important, the problem is about changing the signature of the method to subclass (Bmw) and then it becomes invalid about the override.

Comment: "how I can change my method to make it concrete and not break override signature?" - You can't.

Comment: @JimmyB are you sure? :) If yes it means I spend 1day for free while trying to solve it

Comment: It's still not clear what your actual intention is. It seems to me that the answer given by @RavindraRanwala is closest to what you need. The code you show does not make sense: The user-supplied parameter determines the declared return type, but your implementation does not care about that and tries to force a Bmw into it.

Comment: Using a generic method is wrong in the first place. Just use `Car` in the interface and `Bmw` as the return type in the implementing class. In both cases, just receive a `Map<String, Car>`. No need for casts.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not valid. What would happen if someone with a GarrageSimpleImpl reference called it with a different class extending Car? Generics are all about compile time safety and that's why you get this error.

But you can do it like so,

```
public interface GarrageSimple<T extends Car> {
     T getCar(Map<String, T> c);
}


public class GarrageSimpleImpl implements GarrageSimple<Bmw> {
    @Override
    public Bmw getCar(Map<String, Bmw> c) {
        return new Bmw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, as I mentioned in question I know this solution but I don't want to touch my class, without that it is not possible to override method?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A generic method (a method which declares its own type parameters) means that your method must work no matter what the type parameters (here `T`) are. The method cannot choose what `T` to use. The caller can call your method with `T` being anything within the bounds of `T`, and your method must work correctly with whatever `T` is without choice.

A subclass overriding a method in a superclass means that the subclass method must be a valid substitute for the overridden method, which means that it must work in all situations that the overridden method can be called in. Since the overridden method is generic, and works for any `T`, your subclass method that overrides it must also work for any `T`. Your method does not work for any `T` -- it fails for any `T` that is not `Bmw`.